# Loop Tools Circle deformation

Tags: transforms

My problem is that when im trying to create a circle on a surface with loop tools' circle tool i end up with tis deformation.[image: Deformation result]

To create the circle i subdivide the surface, delete the inner faces that i dont need and select the loop thats going to be my circle. Then i hit the circle tool and the deformation appears. If i create a seperate object no matter the "scales" or any transformation i apply to it the prosess above will be successfull. Clearly i am missing something but i cant find it. Thanks for your time.

ps. im relatively new to blender so anything at all would help

Comment: I assume scale is applied?  (Ctrl+A > Scale)

Comment: Can i ask why i should apply a scale? and what is the purpose of that? no i didnt apply a scale to answer your question

Comment: Applying scale makes all transforms relative to the object the same as if done relative to the world scale. If you scaled your object and did not apply scale, it could cause this.

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate your help. I have one last question. How often should i use the Apply function (Apply scale or rotation)? I must use it every time i scale or rotate my mesh?

Comment: @Nikos Makris, about applying transforms it is already explained here - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation. Shortly, you may want apply transforms if you made them in `Object Mode`. If in `Edit Mode`, then you don't need to do that.